# Detect Keyboard sequence and pattern in java application

Tags: java, keyboard, sequences

In password strength calculator is there an algorithm to determine the keyboard pattern? there could be thousands if not millions of patterns that could be generated with a standard qwerty keyboard. How does a password strength calculator find the strength of password from keyboard pattern?